# Prove that if $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a function, $D \subseteq A$, and $E \subseteq A$ then $f(D) - f(E) \subseteq f(D - E)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that if $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a function, $D \subseteq A$, and $E \subseteq A$ then $f(D) - f(E) \subseteq f(D - E)$.

My method:

Let $y \in f(D) - f(E)$. Hence $y \in f(D)$ and $y \notin f(E)$ then $\exists x \in D$. We can then say that $f(x) = y$. We claim $x \notin E$; then $x \notin A$.

After this would I proceed to prove the other direction or would there be more to the first part than I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said: let $y\in f(D)\setminus f(E)$. Then, $y\in f(D)$ and $y\notin f(E)$. Hence, there is an $x\in D$ such that $f(x)=y$. Suppose that $x\in E$. Then, we would get that $y\in f(E)$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, it must be that $x\notin E$. That is, $x\in D\setminus E$. Hence, $y\in f(D\setminus E)$, since $f(x)=y$.